# What can I do when I accidentally powered a Sony A7s II with 20v instead of 9v?

Tags: sony, repair, equipment-damage

I have been using an off-brand battery coupler in combination with a 9v external battery and it has worked beautifully. Tonight the voltage on the external battery was accidentally changed to 20v instead of 9v, and before I noticed, the camera was turned on. The camera never turned and it still will not.

Has anyone ever done this? Is there a way to get this up and going again or am I going to have to send this in? Who fixes this type issue?

Comment: What kind of insurance did you have on the camera?

Comment: It won't address your current problem sadly, and you essentially now know this, but it's still worth noting. | When using equipment of high value with an external power supply it should NEVER be possible to "accidentally" supply excessive voltage or to connect the supply incorrectly. Ideally protective circuits should be used to ensure that an out of spec power supply will not cause problems. || If you are lucky you may have damaged only the voltage conversion and power supply circuitry in the camera but it is by no means certain that this is the case.

Answer (score 6):

I think you really know the answer here in your heart. You broke it. Pretty much the only place that can fix it is the vendor — Sony. The electronics are fried. Someone needs to figure out what exactly what components are dead and replace them. Possibly Sony will do this for less than the cost of a whole new camera — but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

If the camera is lucky, a built-in fuse blew before more damage occured.  Whether this will serve to let anybody repair the circuit board is anybody's guess though.  A repair shop these days is not authorized to do anything but exchange the circuit board in question, anyway.  But with luck, it's only one board that got fried.

"off-brand battery coupler", "external battery", "changed to 20V" (how do you change the voltage of a battery, by the way?).  Sounds like saving a few dollars less using more dedicated equipment could be called for next time.